# ng2 moment amTimeAgo for 3days

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-moment

Am using  moment js for date conversion in my project, with the framework of angular Js 2. Here am using **amTimeAgo**  pipe for convert timestamp to date and it works correctly (Ex , 10 seconds ago , 1 day ago and 5 days ego , etc...). Here my requirement is , if the current date is greater than 3 days of a post , i need to show the date like, (7-04-2017) instead of (4 days ago).  What is the best way to do this?

```
<span>{{ideaListObj.cDate | amTimeAgo:true }} </span>
```

Comment: best way is to create a custom pipe that will check for the date and output what you expect.

Comment: write a pipe.then(post a code)

Answer (score 0):

ng2 moment uses momentjs to show relative time, so you can customize `amTimeAgo` output using the [`relativeTime`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/).

In your case you can use the following code in the configuration phase:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  relativeTime : {
    future: function (number, withoutSuffix, key, isFuture){
      if( moment(number, 'D-MM-YYYY', true).isValid() ){
        return number;
      }
      return "in " + number;
    },
    past: function (number, withoutSuffix, key, isFuture){
      if( moment(number, 'D-MM-YYYY', true).isValid() ){
        return number;
      }
      return number + " ago";
    },
    dd: function (number, withoutSuffix, key, isFuture){
      if( number >= 3 ){
        return moment().subtract(number, 'd').format('D-MM-YYYY');
      }
      return "%d days";
    }
  }
});
```